# When moving from page to page on site, URL increases in length with repeating additional strings separated by & - how to control?

Tags: 7, uri

I've notices in several situations on my site that the URL length increases with additional strings (arguments, parameters)

This happens including when Views are being used, for example, this URL fragment when browsing pages with maps:
`field_geofield_distance%5Bdistance%5D=100&field_geofield_distance%5Bunit%5D=3959&field_geofield_distance%5Borigin%5D=so14+7dw#field_geofield_distance%5Bdistance%5D=100&field_geofield_distance%5Bunit%5D=3959&field_geofield_distance%5Borigin%5D=se20%208az&zoom=10&lat=51.01656&lon=-1.6389&layers=BTT`

Not just on maps Views but other kinds of Views. The strings repeat in the URL which means they are superfluous - only once occurrence is necessary.

How can I control this - i.e. stop the repeating, and also minimise the need to use % in the URL? (Another way to answer this might be: what is the root cause of these extraneous strings in the URL?)

Comment: Try enabling Ajax in the views

Comment: Thanks AnAnD that does reduce it but I would need to do some reserch to look at the root cause of this 'growing' prepending to URL that I am having as enabling AJAX seems causes my context filter values to not reaching all the panels (containing views) on the page when a button within one of them is clicked - a full page reload ensures that this works. It seems like AJAX deals with the *symptoms* of the problem and not the root of the problem - i.e. the URL generation and interpretation code should not repeat appending of the same value already in the URL.

Comment: I fully agree with you..